# How to get value of "this" keyword inside window's scroll event listener in Angular2?

Tags: angular

I have a function in my component class where I attach scroll event listener. I am doing this:

```
private _scrollListener(event){
    console.log("inside the scroll listener; this: ",this);
    this._zone.run(() => {
        this.checkForLazyLoad = !this.checkForLazyLoad;
    })
}

ngOnInit() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this._scrollListener);
}
```

Problem is that the value of "this" keyword in the private function "_scrollListener" points to window object. How would I get the value of my class' instance inside scroll event listener?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```ts
ngOnInit() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this._scrollListener.bind(this);
}
```

or probably a better solution

```ts
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
private _scrollListener(event){
    console.log("inside the scroll listener; this: ",this);
    this._zone.run(() => {
        this.checkForLazyLoad = !this.checkForLazyLoad;
    })
}
```

this way you can't unregister the event imperatively, but it's unregistered automatically when the component is removed.

Comment: One of my concerns is to be able to attach or detach the listener.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following:

```
private _scrollListener(event){
  console.log("inside the scroll listener; this: ",this);
  this._zone.run(() => {
    this.checkForLazyLoad = !this.checkForLazyLoad;
  })
}

ngOnInit() {
  window.addEventListener("scroll", (event) => {
    this._scrollListener(event);
  });
}
```

It's because you reference the function so you lose it's execution context (i.e. the component itself). This way you will keep the `this` keyword.

Be careful with the `bind` method with TypeScript:

- https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/bind.html

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by simply using **arrow function** :

```
private _scrollListener(event){
    console.log("inside the scroll listener; this: ",this);
    this._zone.run(() => {
        this.checkForLazyLoad = !this.checkForLazyLoad;
    })
}

ngOnInit() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", (event) => {
        this._scrollListener(event);
    });
}
```